# Node cannot call method 'serializeUser' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js

I'm using Passport to create an authentication system with Google. I'm following [this](http://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript/easy-node-authentication-google) tutorial. However, in my passport.js file I keep getting this error:

```
D:\Programming\weebly-site\config\passport.js:11
        passport.serializeUser(function(user, done){
                 ^
TypeError: Cannot call method 'serializeUser' of undefined
  at module.exports (D:\Programming\weebly-site\config\passport.js:11:11)
  at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Programming\weebly-site\routes\admin.js:9:46)
  at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Programming\weebly-site\routes\admin.js:39:4)
  at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
  at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
  at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
  at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
  at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
  at require (module.js:380:17)
  at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Programming\weebly-site\app.js:18:19)
  at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
  at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
  at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
  at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
  at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
  at require (module.js:380:17)
  at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Programming\weebly-site\bin\www:3:11)
  at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
  at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
  at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
  at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
  at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
  at startup (node.js:119:16)
  at node.js:906:3
```

Here's my passport.js file:

```
var GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google-oauth').OAuth2Strategy;

var User = require('../models/users.js');

var configAuth = require('./auth.js');


module.exports = function(passport) {   

    passport.serializeUser(function(user, done){
        done(null, user.id);
    });

    passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
        User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
            done(err, user);
        });
    });
    passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
        clientID        : configAuth.googleAuth.clientID,
        clientSecret    : configAuth.googleAuth.clientSecret,
        callbackURL     : configAuth.googleAuth.callbackURL,
    }, 
    function(token, refreshToken, profile, done) {
        process.nextTick(function() {
            User.findOne({ 'google.id' : profile.id}, function(err, user) {
                if(err)
                    return done(err);

                if(user) {
                    return done(null, user);
                } else {
                    var newUser         = new User();
                    newUser.google.id = profile.id;
                    newUser.google.token = token;
                    newUser.google.name = profile.displayName;
                    newUser.google.email = profile.emails[0].value;

                    newUser.save(function(err){
                        if(err)
                            throw err;
                        return done(null, newUser);
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    }));
};
```

App.js file:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var coffeeScript = require('coffee-script');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var passport = require('passport');
var flash = require('connect-flash');
var session = require('express-session');

var configDB = require('./config/database.js');
mongoose.connect(configDB.url);
require('./config/passport.js')(passport);

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var adminRoutes = require('./routes/admin')
var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();


app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/admin',adminRoutes);
app.use('/users', users);

 ....
app.use(session({secret: 'lotsofwords', saveUninitialized: true, resave: true}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
....

module.exports = app;
```

Admin.js

```
// Generated by CoffeeScript 1.8.0
(function() {
  var express, isLoggedIn, pasport, passport, router;

  express = require('express');

  passport = require('passport');

  require('../config/passport.js')(passport);

  router = express.Router();

  isLoggedIn = function(req, res, next) {
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
      return next();
    }
    res.redirect("/admin");
  };

  router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    return res.render('admin/admin_index.jade');
  });

  router.get('/editor', function(req, res) {
    return res.render('admin/admin_editor.jade');
  });

  router.get('/auth/google', passport.authenticate('google', {
    scope: ['profile', 'email']
  }));

  router.get('/auth/google/callback', passport.authenticate('google', {
    successRedirect: '/editor',
    failureRedirect: '/'
  }));

  module.exports = router;

}).call(this);
```

I have no idea how to fix this - I've searched around on SO and google to no avail. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking in the wrong file. The error is in `D:\Programming\weebly-site\routes\admin.js:9:46`. You are calling the `config/passport.js` exported function without passing in the passport module.

Comment: I've added in my admin.js file - can you explain your third  statement?

Comment: The error message suggested you probably had `require('../config/passport.js')();` or `require('../config/passport.js')(passportWithATypo);` such that the passport module function argument was undefined, causing the exception when your code tried `passport.serializeUser`. There's nothing especially confusing here, you just made a simple mistake, most likely.

Answer (score 0):

where did you placed the require statement?
     require('./config/passport')(**passport**);

note the bolded passport.

did you establish the passport variable above it or below it?

this works:

1. var passport = require('passport');
2. require('./config/passport')(passport); // pass passport for configuration

else (this fails):

1. require('./config/passport')(passport); // pass passport for configuration
2. var passport = require('passport');